# React Native Output Number Format

Tags: android, react-native

i'm new to React-Native Programming.

How to convert decimals number?
Example

Output :  96,78337460961582%

But I want to covert to 96,78%

my current code was

```
<Text style ={styles.textA}>Your Result {ResultA}%</Text>
```

How?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `Number.prototype.toFixed` in Javascript.

```
<Text style={styles.textA}>Your Result {ResultA.toFixed(2)}%</Text>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed